# Do Lifecycle method's trigger again on setState?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating a live weather update app that gives info about the weather by entering the city name and country code. I am using Reactjs to fetch data from https://openweathermap.org API. I am good and have no problem fetching data from it. I am calling a state changing method that changes the initial state of city name and country code by user provided input and my app fetches data from API on clicking the submit button. But every time the input changes, it seems the app fetches data(on seeing console) and after clicking the submit button I get the initial output upon the initial state that I had set. Here is the sample of that API  http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

The response can be either XML or JSON. Though I want JSON. Here is my code:

```
const PATH_BASE='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/';
const PATH_WEATHER='weather?q=';
const APPID='&appid=71a134a1be2190f78ba5301defa7e44f';
const DEFAULT_CITY='karachi';
const DEFAULT_CC='pk';
const COMMA=',';

 class App extends Component {
   constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state={result:null,cityName:DEFAULT_CITY,countryCode:DEFAULT_CC};
   this.setResult=this.setResult.bind(this);
   this.setCity=this.setCity.bind(this);
   this.setCountry=this.setCountry.bind(this);
   this.fetchWeatherUpdates=this.fetchWeatherUpdates.bind(this);
   this.searchSubmit=this.searchSubmit.bind(this);
   }

  fetchWeatherUpdates(cityName,countryCode){
    fetch(`${PATH_BASE}${PATH_WEATHER}${cityName}${COMMA}${countryCode}${APPID}`)
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(result=>this.setResult(result))
    .catch(error=>error);  
  }
 componentDidMount(){
    const {cityName,countryCode}=this.state;
    this.fetchWeatherUpdates(cityName,countryCode);
  }
 setResult(result){
   this.setState({result:result});
 }
 setCity(event){
   this.setState({cityName:event.target.value});
 }
 setCountry(event){
   this.setState({countryCode:event.target.value});
 }


 searchSubmit(){
   const {cityName,countryCode}=this.state;
   this.fetchWeatherUpdates(cityName,countryCode);
 }

 render() {
 const {cityName,countryCode}=this.state;
 console.log(this.state.result);
 if(!this.state.result){
   return (<div>Loading...</div>);
 }
 return (
  <div className="App">
  <form onSubmit={this.searchSubmit}>
  <input type="text" value={this.state.cityName} onChange={this.setCity}/>
  <input type="text" value={this.state.countryCode} onChange={this.setCountry}/>
  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
  </form>
  <h2>
     {this.state.result.weather[0].main}
  </h2>
  </div>
 );
 }
}


export default App;
```

*Sorry for the long code but I added all so that might help you in answering and may reveal my stupid mistake....*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` will only run when the component is mounted, so it will not run again if you use `setState`.

You are not preventing the default behavior of the browser in your submit handler, which is to reload the browser. By preventing it it will not reload on submit.

**Example**

```
class App extends Component {
  // ...

  searchSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { cityName, countryCode } = this.state;
    this.fetchWeatherUpdates(cityName, countryCode);
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks..... Now I get new output on each submit and the browser isn't reloading....

Comment: I have to wait for accepting as I just asked the question and you immediately answered so stackoverflow wasn't allowing me to do so.......